# How to resolve webview error when i integrate myapplication to login with instagram

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, instagram

[image]

I have tried this

```
 private void setUpWebView() {
        mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new OAuthWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.clearFormData();
        mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);

//Make sure no caching is done
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(mWebView.getSettings().LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        mWebView.clearHistory();

//Make sure no autofill for Forms/ user-name password happens for the app
        mWebView.clearFormData();
        mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);

        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        Log.d("TAG", "onPageFinished URL:" + mUrl);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
        mContent.addView(mWebView);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this line for enable cookies for your WebView:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```